# Change Row/Cell color in LightSwitch 2010

Tags: c#, grid, conditional-statements, visual-studio-lightswitch

If I have a page which show a list of Hotels (rows from 1 till 500). I want to change the row color to red.
For example row one has 5 columns:

---

```
Name      Age      Email      Tel      Salary      Gender_Man

Mo        25       xxx@x.com  12546    10          Yes
```

Action: If `Gender_Man == True`, then change the row color to red.

Since I am new to C# please tell me where and how I can do this in light switch?

[image]

Comment: why the negative rating?

Answer (score 1):

I've done this but in VB.NET. However, I my solution was adapted from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c375cb81-3cbd-4d76-8b0d-d2fd06c5a4b8/changing-row-color-based-on-a-condition-on-a-column?forum=lightswitch) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e901f2c7-a416-46ff-8144-c7b6ab3af31d/modifying-background-color-of-datagrid-based-on-data-in-grid?forum=lightswitch) which have examples in C#, though some of the links to example classes are broken.

Basically you need to create a method that will bind a converter class to each row as it is being loaded. That binding will take a specific column name, for you it would be `Gender_Man`. In the links above, they are using the column `Status` and are able to bind just using the column name. My column name was `Color` and I had to use `New Binding("Details.Entity.Color")` so you might need to play around with this.

The converter class is a very simple subclass of `IValueConverter` and has to implement a constructor which you can leave empty, `Convert` which tests the value of the column and returns a `SolidColorBrush` object with the ARGB value you want the background to be, and `ConvertBack` which just throws an exception.

Also, just a quick critique, there are more genders these days than just male and female so using a boolean to capture this information is probably going to lead to headaches down the line. Better to use a string and perhaps make a choice list for proper validation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with for this problem, as a more generic solution for LS 2015.

Given: I have a data grid named MySpecialConfigurationGrid

Given: MySpecialConfigurationGrid's underlying EF type is MySpecialConfiguration

Given: The column-cell I want to colorize and use as the source of the color information is called MyColor

Given: This code goes into the code behind for the LSML.

```
    void proxy_ControlAvailable(object sender, ControlAvailableEventArgs e)
    {
        var ctrl = (DataGrid)e.Control;
        ctrl.LoadingRow += new EventHandler<DataGridRowEventArgs>(Ctrl_LoadingRow);
    }

    private void Ctrl_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        //Getting a particular cell is tricky, 
        // you have cross reference the row instance in the particular
        // column you want to find, and then get that thing's parent, 
        // which happens to be the DataGridCell you can control the rendering of.
        DataGrid grid = (DataGrid)sender;
        DataGridRow row = new DataGridRow();
        row = e.Row;
        var cell = (grid.Columns.First(item => item.SortMemberPath == nameof(MySpecialConfiguration.MyColor))
            .GetCellContent(row) as Microsoft.LightSwitch.Presentation.Framework.ContentItemPresenter)
            .Parent as DataGridCell;

        Binding bgbinding = new Binding(nameof(MySpecialConfiguration.MyColor))
        {
            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
            Converter = new RowColorConverter(),
            ValidatesOnExceptions = true
        };
        cell.SetBinding(DataGridCell.BackgroundProperty, bgbinding);
    }

    partial void MySpecialConfiguration_InitializeDataWorkspace(global::System.Collections.Generic.List<global::Microsoft.LightSwitch.IDataService> saveChangesTo)
    {
        Microsoft.LightSwitch.Threading.Dispatchers.Main.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            var proxy = this.FindControl(nameof(MySpecialConfigurationGrid));
            proxy.ControlAvailable += new EventHandler<ControlAvailableEventArgs>(proxy_ControlAvailable);
        });
    }

    public class RowColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public RowColorConverter() { }
        #region IValueConverter Members
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                var match = Regex.Match(value as string, "#(?<R>[a-fA-F0-9]{2})(?<G>[a-fA-F0-9]{2})(?<B>[a-fA-F0-9]{2})");

                if (match.Success)
                {
                    return new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,
                        sToB(match.Groups["R"].Value),
                        sToB(match.Groups["G"].Value),
                        sToB(match.Groups["B"].Value)));
                }
            }

            return new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255));
        }

        private byte sToB(string s)
        {
            return byte.Parse(s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();

        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Basically, the way it works is you attach events to the creation of the row, then tie into the row's loading event. From there, you can access the data grid itself and its visual tree. Do some trickery to get a reference to the DataGridCell, and then add a Binding with an IValueConverter to its Background dependency property. The IValueConverter parses an HTML hex color triplet string into component parts and returns a SolidColorBrush from that.

For your specific Gender_Man = true thing, adjust the ValueConverter to accept the appropriate value, and change the nameof() calls in the other bits of the code to reference the appropriate columns for binding (the binding attaches to the color column), and the cell to find the target column you wish to colorize.